# Modern UI Metro Framework HTML label text color

Tags: c#

I am trying to change the color of an html Metro Framework label but but it stays black. I tried through the VS property windows or using code:

```
lbl_errorMsg.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

I searched for a bug in the framework (MetroModernUI v1.4.0) but did not find anything. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Metro in WPF

You can use

```
lbl_errorMsg.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I use metro framework and an html label. The foreground property is not available on this item.